# Restrict certain endpoints in Swagger .net core with api-key

Tags: c#, api, swagger

I have a net core 2.2 project with apicontrollers, EF, and I use latest swashbuckle swagger for net core 4.0.1

Its set up, everything is working, its showing all the api endpoints from the controllers in swagger.

The problem: We want to secure this api by using api-keys in the header of the requests. We want user A to only se for example, /GetAllUsers in usercontroller, but user B can see all the api endpoints in usercontroller.

I have yet to find an example that does this.

This is my thoughts. 
Scenario one: User A goes to the api adress and gets prompted for a username and password (password is apikey) and we check the database if there is a username and password that matches. If so, we direct the user to the swagger view/endpoints that this user has access to.

Scenario two: send the apikey in the header and we check the db and return the correct view.

Is this doable?

This is what my startup looks like, and this an extension method for swagger/startup where I configure it.

startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddUnitOfWork();
 services.AddHelpers();

 services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), 
 typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
 services.AddMediatR();
 services.AddConfiguredSwagger(); // <--- extension
 services.AddMvc()
 .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure 
the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

 // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();
}


// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", 
typeof(Startup).Namespace);
options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

app.UseMvc();

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
});
}
```

Extension

```
public static class SwaggerServiceCollectionExtensions
{
public static IServiceCollection AddConfiguredSwagger(this 
IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
    return services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = 
        typeof(Startup).Namespace, Version = "v1" });
        var xmlFile = $" 
    {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
 }
}
```